# juggernaut: command not found

Tags: rubygems

Am trying to install juggernaut following the steps [here](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) juggernaut -c juggernaut.yml, I got "juggernaut: command not found", any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, after reading the README file in the /vendor/Juggernaut_plugin, I realized that there was a missing gem which named 'maccman-juggernaut' installed through "gem install maccman-juggernaut -s http://gems.github.com". After installing this gem the command juggernaut worked for me for the server and configure. Push notifications is very important and I hope the documentation of juggernaut to be enhanced soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and its because I was installing the older version.  I don't know why they don't update the rubyforge page with the new info >:|

go [here](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut) to get Juggernaut 2!

Answer (score 0):

use npm install -g to get the command installed

or just:
node juggernaut/server.js &